# Lucene - First Application Error

Tags: java, lucene

I want to use `Lucene` for the first time and I used this tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_first_application.htm

However, I got error in `indexer.java` file stating

> "the method open(path) in the type FSdirectory is not applicable for the arguments "

I exactly followed the tutorial and I am a beginner, so I appreciate any idea or hints.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to import `FileSystems` and `Path` below. Your imported criteria may be wrong.

1. FileSystems: `import java.nio.file.FileSystems;`
2. Path: `import java.nio.file.Path;`

N.B:

> Unfortunately, because of system peculiarities, there is no single
>   overall best implementation. Therefore, we've added the
>   open**(java.nio.file.Path)** method, to allow `Lucene` to choose the best
>   `FSDirectory` implementation given your environment, and the known
>   limitations of each implementation. For users who have no reason to
>   prefer a specific implementation, it's best to simply use
>   open`(java.nio.file.Path)`. For all others, you should instantiate the
>   desired implementation directly.

Related Link: https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html